# webrtc, connects fine and receives stream, yet no picture nor audio

Tags: typescript, webrtc

I've been working on this webrtc peer-to-peer functionality and it appears the connection is working fine, I even get the "ontrack" event raised with both an audio and video track. 
However when adding the stream to a  element, nothing seemingly happens. 
Even though I get the Progress event constantly raised on the  element I never get a "play", "playing", "loadeddata" or "loadedmetadata". I also tried invoking play() myself upon the progress event, this didn't work either.

Could it be because I only use STUN servers and no TURN server? I failed to find any decent documentation on whether both are needed.
Also I might add I'm testing this on two Android phones running on their respective mobile data connection (no shared Wi-Fi between them)

All the code is written in a typescript class, which can be seen here: https://hastebin.com/zajegiqage.ts

And the html is as simple as:

```
<video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
<video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>

<button type="button" id="callButton">Call</button>
<button type="button" id="hangupButton">Hang Up</button>

<script>new VideoChat(42);</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed because I needed a TURN server. After setting one up, everything works fine.